# Why is it considered compulsory for brahmins to perform sandhyavandanam?

Tags: rituals, sandhyavandanam

Although it has been mentioned that it is considered compulsory, the reason why is not mentioned?
Also, are there any shortcuts? Like performing sandhyavandanam only once a day or once a week?
Also, what are the benefits gained by doing sandhyavandanam?

Comment: Sandhya = sun and moon together. Sandhyavandhanam directly is a method of worshiping the unmanifest Brahman which is in light form for brahmanas. Sandhya is Nithya karma where you should not work for benefit but if you do not do as Brahamana you incur sin. Sandhya one alone can take you to greater heights of you are brahmana

Comment: although it is mentioned that going to office is compulsory, the reason why is not mentioned. are there any shortcuts like going to office only 1 hour per day, or once a week ? also, what are the benefits of going to office and working.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS, i don't think it's sun and moon together - that is amavasya. also we can see moon many times during daytime. sandhya is day & night together.

Comment: @Ram your answer is cheeky, but I love it.  Instruction by analogy

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Sandhyavandanam is recommended was told by Sri Ramakrishna to his disciples.

Gospel / Volume 1 / [Pundit Shashadhar](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/24_pundit_shashadhar.htm):

> Without having realized God one cannot give up rituals altogether. **How long should one practise the sandhya and other forms of ritualistic worship? As long as one does not shed tears of joy at the name of God and feel a thrill in one's body.** You will know that your ritualistic worship has come to an end when your eyes become filled with tears as you repeat 'Om Rama'. Then you do not have to continue your sandhya or other rituals. When the fruit appears the blossom drops off.

As long as one is not realized, Sandhyavandanam should be practiced because after realization, one cannot perform such actions.

Gospel / Volume 1 / [The Master And His Injured Arm](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/19_master_and_injured_arm.htm):

> In the case of a paramahamsa, like Sukadeva, all karmas — all puja, japa, tarpan, sandhya, and so forth — drop away. In this state a man communes with God through the mind alone. Sometimes he may be pleased to perform outward activities for the welfare of mankind. But his recollection and contemplation of God remain uninterrupted.

Gospel / Volume 1 / [Pundit Shashadhar](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/24_pundit_shashadhar.htm):

> The sandhya merges in the Gayatri, the Gayatri in Om, and Om in samadhi. It is like the sound of a bell: t — a — m. The yogi, by following in the trail of the sound Om, gradually merges himself in the Supreme Brahman. His sandhya and other ritualistic duties disappear in samadhi. Thus the duties of the jnani come to an end.

At the start of one's spiritual journey, one should perform Sandhyavandanam but upon reaching higher level, these actions automatically drop off.